# Positioning issue for DIVS on different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9BwSBW5V0yqaGxOdW9vQ2xKckk/edit

First image: Google Chrome
Second image: Mozilla Firefox
Third image: Internet Explorer

I would need all my browsers to show like in Chrome.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Please provide code sample in http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I cannot provide code samples :( . I know that the problem and the solution can be found in cross-browser migration. I tried several  approaches but if I make it to work on Firefox then it won't work on Chrome. I also read that in this case we should use CSS Reset but I do not know how to use it. Thank's though for your reply :)

Comment: What even is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by you "cannot provide code samples"? We are not asking you to duplicate your entire site — just a **minimal replica** of your issue would be sufficient. Also, do not use link shorteners on SO to mask original URLs, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you havent posted your code here, it will be extremely difficult for anyone to give you the exact answer.

For me it seems like the problem is that the container div of the navigation-elements you have does not have a set width and height that is big enough to contain all the elements. Try setting a width and a height to this element.